# Not getting correct URI from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm brand new to stack overflow so apologizes in advance if I do anything wrong :).

I'm trying to create an intent to return a image from the sdCard, I will then use BitmapFactory to change the revolution. However the intent is not returning the right file name I think. I have provided the error logs below along with the intent creation and what I want to do with the result back (onActivityResult()).

Error Logs:

```
01-10 18:51:34.043: E/BitmapFactory(15528): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /IMG-20160110-WA0001.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-10 18:51:34.044: E/BitmapFactory(15528): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /IMG-20160110-WA0001.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)


01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528): Process: com.example.george.soundboard, PID: 15528
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:38261 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.george.soundboard/com.example.george.soundboard.ChooseElement}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at com.example.george.soundboard.ChooseElement.onActivityResult(ChooseElement.java:210)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
01-10 18:51:34.046: E/AndroidRuntime(15528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
```

The intent creation:

```
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
                    pickIntent.setType("image/*");
                    pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And onActivityResult():

```
File i = new File(getFileName(data.getData()));

SetActivity.bluePrint[SetActivity.id].image = decodeImage(i, 100, 100);

                    image.setImageBitmap(SetActivity.bluePrint[SetActivity.id].image);

public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getPath();
            int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (cut != -1) {
                result = result.substring(cut + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

public static Bitmap decodeImage(File file, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for helping :) Of course if there's anymore information needed please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getFileName()` method is useless (as you don't need it) and wrong (as `DISPLAY_NAME` does not return a path). Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to open an `InputStream` on the content pointed to by the `Uri`. Pass that to `decodeStream()` on `BitmapFactory`.

Better yet, get rid of most of this code, and use a library like Picasso to populate your `ImageView` with the image from the `Uri` asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you, that's saved me so much code, I've got rid of the getFileName() and decodeBitmap() and used Picasso as shown below: Picasso.with(image.getContext()).load(SetActivity.bluePrint[SetActivity.id].image).resize(300,300).into(image);